# Disable real-time error checking in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, error-checking

Intellij IDEA checks errors as you type. Is there a way to just check for errors after you save the file? In Eclipse this is done by unchecking "General - Editors - Structured Text Editors'-> 'Report problems as you type". Is there a similar feature in Intellij IDEA?

Comment: Well you could disable inspections (which ones - all?). Or isn't there some timeout for this (usually 200ms?) - you could try increasing that too if error analysis really annoys you so much ;)

Comment: In IntelliJ you don't save the file -- that happens automatically as you type too. What problems are you having with this feature?

Comment: The timeout solution seems what I am looking for. Basically my problem is that I don't like seeing errors (red lines, warnings etc) as a type because a lot of times I'm for example writing functions that don't exist yet. In eclipse I can disable the error checking as a type and when I save the file, Eclipse would report all the errors. I was hoping i could have something similar in Intellij IDEA.

Comment: Stop using IntelliJ like an Eclipse, it just does not work that way. If you write a function that does not exist then just alt+enter, enter and it is created.

Comment: I agree with @Meo -- don't try to use IntelliJ like Eclipse, otherwise you won't see the benefits. Having a red line in your code shouldn't irritate you, it should inform and guide you. You can use it to navigate (using F2), and you can then hit alt-enter to have idea suggest fixes for the problems, such as generating the missing functions or completing incomplete lines.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create your java file (or any file for that matter) exclude it from the source directory (you can do that in Module Settings -> source tab), this way the compiler wont scan that file for any compile time errors

Hope that helps

K